~~My Profession~~
Edited to change her name to "Diana" to make more sense

I first met Diana over a decade ago, and we quickly became friends. We don't talk often, but I am always overjoyed to see her.
I still think back to the day I first met her:

Well, it was a day like any other. I don't remember what my buddy (now housemate) Alexis was up to, but I knew I would be looking for Diana today. After heading outside, I noticed a note on my car's hood.


"[My name], if you want to see me, you need to bring Byron with you."
Of course! I needed our mutual friend Byron! I then called him, as it was best to reach him by phone.


I called Byron on the phone and he was quick to pick up. He told me he would be ready to come over after cooking. "Alright, see you soon, Byron."

After Byron showed up we both headed down to find Diana, and we met her after some time. The three of us spent the night at my place, where I got to spend some time with Diana. Unlike Byron, she doesn't know how to cook, but she makes some of the best clothes I've ever seen!

Who is Diana? And who am I?
Hint 1:

This requires some video game knowledge from a game that released over a decade ago

Hint 2:

A single word can be discovered from each blockquote by using the italicized portions.

Hint 3:

Why can Diana make really good clothes? And why can't she cook while Byron can?


Welcome to PSE, enjoy your stay. Your puzzle looks to be self-made, but just in case: did you find this elsewhere? If so, please provide attribution for it.

Got it. And yes I made this puzzle myself.

@Brodin Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

Partial answer:
You are

Steven

because

 You can notice by looking at the first and third word pairs, you can read words across them by removing parts of their center: W(ELL H)OOD and I (BY)RON, or WOOD and IRON. By this logic, for section two we're looking for a material that is 'between' Wood and Iron and ends with some end of the word PHONE. The best fit for this is STONE, meaning our name should start with ST. There's one famous game with a starting progression of Wood, Stone, Iron: Minecraft. This is confirmed by our housemate being named ALEX(is), the secondary Minecraft skin, and that the main skin, Steve, starts with ST. Hence, our name should start with STEVE. The only reasonable fit for this is STEVEN. I'm unsure how Jada fits in with this though.


Ahh you're basically there! I'll make an edit to make it a bit better
